# Discover the ip "ghost"

Tags: ip

I found a strange ip on my machine lan

```
192.168.56.100
```

I'm using virtualbox with host-only network(192.168.56.1) for
secure network with old machines.

```
arping2     192.168.56.100
```

answers with two different mac address!

nmap and ping fail(?)

How to discover the ip source?

Of course `ifconfig -a |grep 56.100` return nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VirtualBox, click Preferences > Network > Host-only networks > Edit (screw driver icon) > DHCP server. There you can see 192.168.56.100 is the default DHCP server in the virtual host-only network. It won't respond to `ping`; `nmap` and `ping` should both fail by default. You might try flushing both arp entries from the arp table and try `arping2` again.